# glDrawArrays problem

Tags: opengl-es

I have a draw routine fully working as follows:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture name]);
    GLsizei stride = sizeof(quads[0].tl);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TQuad2D), quads, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, stride, (void *)offsetof(TVertex2D, pos));
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, stride, (void *)offsetof(TVertex2D, tex));
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And either before or after the above, I want to draw a simple line such as the one below. This by itself is working fine, but if I combine it with the above routine it gives me a 506 error, which is `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`.

```
GLfloat verts[4];
verts[0] = 0;
verts[1] = 0;
verts[2] = 600;
verts[3] = 600;

glColor4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &verts);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
GLErrCheck(@"err");
```

I am probably forgetting to reset some GL state, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption about forgetting to reset some state is correct. As long as a buffer is bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, the last parameter to glVertexPointer and similar functions is interpreted as an offset into this buffer and not as a regular pointer like `&verts`. You can reset this by calling

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

at the end of your first code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is exactly what was happening!